# vb.net use saveFileDialog with XmlTextWriter

Tags: vb.net

i am new with VB.net

and i manage to write input to xml file using

```
Dim writer As New XmlTextWriter("xmlInputFile.xml", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
```

now i want user to write they own name and path location of the xml file . 
reading couple of example of SaveFileDialog and i come out with this code

```
Dim path As String = IO.Path.GetFullPath(SaveFileDialog1.FileName)
    Dim writer As New XmlTextWriter(ToString(path), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
```

which give an error

thanks

btw the button code below

```
Private Sub Button3_Click_3(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    Dim SaveFileDialog1 As SaveFileDialog = New System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog
    SaveFileDialog1.DefaultExt = ".xml"
    SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "XML files(.xml)|*.xml|all Files(*.*)|*.*"
    SaveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "desktop"

    If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Save_Data()
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: And the error is? How do you expect getting help without saying what actually goes wrong?

Comment: You didn't say what the error was. However, you need to remove the `ToString` (`path` is, already a String). `Dim writer As New XmlTextWriter(path, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)`

Comment: ToString(path) doesn't make sense.  Use CStr() to convert stuff to strings.  But that isn't necessary since it is already a string, so simply use path.

Comment: ups i manage to make it work